# Windows doesn't boot after installing Ubuntu. Returns to Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

I'm new to Ubuntu 12.04. I installed Windows XP (sp3) first, then Ubuntu alongside. Ubuntu boots well but when I choose Win XP from the boot menu it goes to a black screen and then returns to the boot menu

I ran boot-repair and got this [info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6679493/).

But the problem was not fixed.

**Update:**
I tried to run the `fixmbr` command to recover the boot record.  I inserted Windows XP CD and booted from CD, but it doesn't detect my Windows installation.

**Update:**
Recovery Console won't load to press R for repair boot sector

Comment: Because of the "corrupted" PBR, Windows repairs will not work. Windows has to see a NTFS partition and with grub installed into the PBR it is not a valid NTFS partition. If you use testdisk to restore a default NTFS, only then will Windows repairs work. Better just to restore backup if backup is valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

You installed grub2's boot loader to the PBR or partition boot sector of Windows. Windows has to have its boot code in its NTFS partition.

Fix for most, a few have other issues, better than windows fix in many cases as it also fixes other parameters:

This has instructions on using testdisk to repair the install of grub to the boot sector for windows from Ubuntu or Linux LiveCD.

[HowTo] Repair the bootsector of a Windows partition  - YannBuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

You want to get to this screen:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1926510

Answer (score 0):

Finally & unfortunatly delete all partition and do same do as do first, but it works! first install windows and next install ubuntu 11 and dual boot now work! the only difference was this: windows xp first copy files next restart and install windows. when it copy and reboot to continue installation and sure boot record works, i prevent to continue and install win. I reboot from cd and install ubuntu 11 alongside and after that complete installation of windows xp. now both OS boot well.